# Neto Product specific category

Tags: php, web, e-commerce, neto

There are 3 categories in my Neto store:

Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
I want to display ONLY one category i.e Category 2(Specific category) on  the Homepage.

Anyone Know How can i achieve this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this code and apply according to you choice

```
[%thumb_list type:'products' filter_category:'' limit:'10'%]
    [%param template%]
        [%if [@name@] eq 'Shirts'%]
            shirt_template
        [%else%]
            default`enter code here`
        [%/if%]
    [%/param%]
```

Comment: I'm using this code below to pull through categories but can't figure out how to only show my 3 parent categories. It seems to be pulling through all of them.

`[%thumb_list type:'content' content_type:'category' template:'category' limit:'4' sortby:'sortorder'%]
   [%param template%]
    [%if [@name@] eq 'Hytea', 'ToaTea', 'Specials'%]
        shirt_template
    [%else%]
        default`enter code here`
    [%/if%]
[%/param%]`